# AS3 - nulling elements within a Vector structure

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, null, structure

I'm using a Vector structure in ActionScript 3 to store references to a custom class. My Vector is fixed length for performance reasons, and also because it needs to map 1:1 to another data structure.

I'm trying to figure out how I "remove" an element from this fixed list. I don't want the length of the Vector to change, I just want the value of that element to be "null". Or more specifically, when I test for the truth of that element (eg: if (myVector[index]) { // do something... }), I want that test to fail for that element, since it's "empty".

So naturally, I've tried:

```
myVector[index] = null;
```

but that throws a TypeError, as does

```
myVector[index] = Vector.<MyClass>([]);
```

So what's the process for "emptying" an element of a Vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something wrong with your `index` variable because

```
myVector[0] = null;
```

does not throw a TypeError when I try that. Is `index` an int or uint?

Comment: Yeah you're right, as it turns out. I thought it was that line throwing the error because when I commented it out, it stopped giving me the error, and when I uncommented it, the error came back. Unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on how you look at it), this is no longer the case. myVector[index] = null is no longer throwing an error. You may be right that it had more to do with the index than with the null assignment. This makes a ton of sense. I won't accept the answer quite yet until I find out exactly what's behind it.

Comment: I think taking another look at the value that 'index' had when the error was thrown, could help you find the answer. Was it out of bounds? Negative? Not a Number? Undefined? Null itself? Breakpoints usually help me a lot in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

if you're receiving:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access
>   a property or method of a null object
>   reference

than you probably haven't added your class to the object you are trying to manage (IE:  you haven't added your Display objects to the stage that you are trying to nullify)

posting more code could help, but something like the following should work for you:

```
var spriteA:Sprite = new Sprite();
var spriteB:Sprite = new Sprite();
var spriteC:Sprite = new Sprite();

var spritesVector:Vector.<Sprite> = new <Sprite>[spriteA, spriteB, spriteC];
spritesVector.fixed = true;
trace(spritesVector); //[object Sprite],[object Sprite],[object Sprite]

spritesVector[1] = null;
trace(spritesVector); //[object Sprite],null,[object Sprite]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it's I Type Error #1014 I believe. Something about an invalid type going into the vector, which is why I thought the null assignment was causing the failure. Also, do note that you have a syntax error in your code - I think you means var spritesVector:Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>([spriteA, spriteB, spriteC]);

Comment: so the objects you're trying to assign to the vector don't have the same base type, or so it seems from your explanation.  and it's not a syntax error but simply a slightly shorter way to populate a new vector - try it.  you can read more here:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html